# Mount a drive read-write without remounting

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb-flash-drive, mount, read-only

I have a flash drive mounted in read-only mode. I cannot unmount it, but I want to be able to write to it. I tried mounting it in a second place but that didn't work. It is in use, so I cannot unmount it. Is this possible or am I stuck with read only (filesystem is `vfat` if it makes any difference).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mount -o remount,rw
```

is the way to do it on Linux, but which options are changeable varies across filesystems.